# int* 'limits' in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, int

Why is it when I define a pointer to an array of two `int`'s, let's say:

```
int *data;
data = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
```

Then insert some values:

```
*(data) = 22;
*(data+1) = 466;
*(data+2) = 1000;
```

Even though the array only has the size of `2`, if I print the third element I placed in the vector, it will still show correctly? Is it normal or am I changing memory addresses where I shouldn't be meddling with?

Comment: *"or I'm changing memory addresses where I shouldn't be meddling with?"* **That's a bingo!** Access past array bounds is undefined behavior.

Comment: It's Undefined Behaviour. It might appear to work if there is no conflict with anything else, but anything can happen when you index `data[2]`.

Comment: This is what is called an undefined behavior.

Comment: To anyone: please do not spread the bad wording. This [source] is what *leads* to undefined behavior, not what it *is*. Code cannot be undefined behavior, because code and behavior are different categories – the former is producing the latter.